# PHP database selection issue

Tags: php, database-connection

I'm in a bit of a pickle with freshening up my PHP a bit, it's been about 3 years since I last coded in PHP. Any insights are welcomed! I'll give you as much information as I possibly can to resolve this error so here goes!

**Files**

- config.php
- database.php
- news.php
- BLnews.php
- index.php

**Includes**

- config.php -> news.php
- database.php -> news.php
- news.php -> BLnews.php
- BLnews.php -> index.php

Now the problem with my current code is that the database connection is being made but my database refuses to be selected. The query I have should work but due to my database not getting selected it's kind of annoying to get any data exchange going!

**config.php**

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "test";
?>
```

**database.php**

```
<?php
class Database {

    //-------------------------------------------
    //    Connects to the database
    //-------------------------------------------
    function connect() {
        if (isset($dbhost) && isset($dbuser) && isset($dbpass) && isset($dbname)) {
            $con = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
            $selected_db = mysql_select_db($dbname, $con) or die("Could not select test DB");
        }
    }// end function connect
} // end class Database
?>
```

**News.php**

```
<?php
// include the config file and database class
include 'config.php';
include 'database.php';

...
?>
```

**BLnews.php**

```
<?php
// include the news class
include 'news.php';
// create an instance of the Database class and call it $db
$db = new Database;
$db -> connect();

class BLnews {

    function getNews() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM news";
        if (isset($sql)) {
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not execute query. Reason: " .mysql_error());
        }
        return $result;
    }
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
...

include 'includes/BLnews.php';
$blNews = new BLnews();
$news = $blNews->getNews();
?>

...
<?php 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($news))
        {
        echo '<div class="post">';
        echo '<h2><a href="#"> ' . $row["title"] .'</a></h2>';
        echo '<p class="post-info">Posted by <a href="#"> </a> | <span class="date"> Posted on <a href="#">' . $row["date"] . '</a></span></p>';
        echo $row["content"];
        echo '</div>';
        }
        ?>
```

Well this is pretty much everything that should get the information going however due to the mysql_error in `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not execute query. Reason: " .mysql_error());` I can see the error and it says:

> Could not execute query. Reason: No database selected

I honestly have no idea why it would not work and I've been fiddling with it for quite some time now. Help is most welcomed and I thank you in advance!

Greets

Lemon

Comment: Since you've been out of PHP for a little while, you should google PDO.

Comment: Sorry but in your database class I don't see where you define vars as $dbhost or $dbuser. In the case you didn't, the if will be always false so you'll neither get a connection nor a die().

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: He says that the connection is being made, and if you look in his code, the connection will only be made if those variables are all set.

Comment: @Cyclone How can he surely assert this if he don't define those vars?

Comment: I added what's in config.php as well now, maybe it's easier for people to see everything then! Thanks for the replies!

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: `include 'config.php'; include 'database.php';` As Citroenfris says in a comment, they're defined in config.php...

Comment: @Cyclone Do you know that vars **outside** a class can't be seen **inside** a class without passing them in some way (constructor, params and so on)?

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa: I'm going on what OP says to be accurate: `Now the problem with my current code is that the database connection is being made but my database refuses to be selected.`, hence somehow he's connecting to the database with those credentials

Comment: You seem to be right Aurelio, I can't get into the connect function.

Comment: @Cyclone Thus you're changing your previous "sure" assertion. He can't know if the connection is done. That's the error, now way. The connection params are not defined inside the database class.

Comment: @Citroenfris  Glad to read that you understand your error :)

Comment: I guess the easiest solution is just to put the variables from the config file into my DB class and get rid of the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you use in your functions aren't set with a value.  You likely need to convert the variables used to `$this->dbName` etc or otherwise assign values to the variables used.

Edit for users comment about variables defined in `config.php`:

You really should attempt to get the data appropriate for each class inside that class.  Ultimately your variables are available to your entire app, there's no telling at this point if the variable was changed by a file including `config.php` but before `database.php` is called.

I would use a debugging tool and verify the values of the variables or just `var_dump()` them before the call.

Comment: Presumably they're defined in `config.php`...which if you notice, is included prior to `database.php`

Comment: ^this, they are in config.php

Comment: Then I would ensure they are truly defined in `config.php`.  The most likely cause is that the `isset()` checks are failing and the `mysql_select_db` function is not called.

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry: But OP says he's sure the connection is made: `Now the problem with my current code is that the database connection is being made but my database refuses to be selected.`

Comment: Again I counter with, what is the value held in `$dbName`?  If there is indeed a value then what are the error logs saying?

Answer (score 0):

Your Database class methods connect and selectDb try to read from variables that are not set ($dbhost, $dbname, $con, etc). You probably want to pass those values to a constructor and set them as class properties. Better yet, look into PDO (or an ORM) and forget creating your own db class.

Comment: I don't think he should necessarily forget about making the DB class.  It is fairly straightforward to make a MySQLi/PDO connection wrapper and can be a good learning experience.

He should look into an alternative to `mysql_` though.

Comment: @CharlesSprayberry you may be right. However, it does not appear to me that his Database class offers any improvement over what PDO already offers. What might be more useful to him is to create a db connection manager class (handling pdo object(s)). But, I guess it all depends on what he is trying to achieve.